# What are interesting usages of JADE?

Tags: agents, agents-jade

I'm looking for [JADE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Agent_Development_Framework) projects which are noteworthy but I wasn't able to find such a list on the Internet. Could anybody provide some?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Who is using Jade?](http://jade.tilab.com/application-who.htm) The listings are on the old side, however.